# After enabling the rule (proguard-rules.pro), start to give an error I do not understand why

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

When I click on the method that contains the type of such code then I get an error (cannot be cast to).I don't know what else to add to the rules.

ChatFragment chatFragment = (ChatFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentClass.getSimpleName());

```
Android Studio 3.2.1
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 28

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

My rules are :

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Exceptions


-keep class android.support.v7.widget.**{ *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
-keep class javax.annotation.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.common.collect.** { *; }
-keep class com.github.ajalt.reprint.module.** { *; }
-keep class com.samsung.** {*;}
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.** {*;}
-keep interface android.support.v7.* { *; }
-keep class com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.**{ *; }
-keep class org.java-websocket.**{ *; }
-keep class com.github.NaikSoftware.**{ *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.sdk.android.**{ *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.**{ *; }
-keep class com.app.motohq.motohqapp.app.customs.Pair{ *; }



-dontwarn com.github.siyamed.**
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.**
-dontwarn com.pushtorefresh.storio2.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.samsung.**
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
```

---

```
Process: com.app.motohq.motohqapp, PID: 9586
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.app.motohq.motohqapp.ui.a.a.c.c cannot be cast to com.app.motohq.motohqapp.ui.a.g.c
        at com.app.motohq.motohqapp.ui.activities.MessagesActivity.b(MessagesActivity.java:243)
        at com.app.motohq.motohqapp.ui.a.a.c.c.a(MenuLastMessageDialogFragment.java:47)
        at com.app.motohq.motohqapp.d.c.b.a.f.a(MenuChatDialogFragmentView$$State.java:24)
        at com.app.motohq.motohqapp.d.b.a.g.a(MenuChatDialogFragmentPresenter.java:22)
        at com.app.motohq.motohqapp.b.x$a.onClick(DialogMenuStatusChatBindingImpl.java:129)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Please share your code as well

Comment: The error is telling you that when you execute `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentClass.getSimpleName());` you do not get back an instance of `ChatFragment` but an instance of a different one. Where is the code that you add the fragment with? Basically `fragmentClass` is not the same class type as `ChatFragment` as it's returning a different class name when calling `getSimpleName`

Comment: I understand that the app wrote in the error message when I disable the rule (proguard-rules.pro), there is no error and everything works well.

Comment: FragmentManager fragmentManager = baseActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName(), 0);
            ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
            ft.replace(content, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
            ft.commit();

Comment: I found a problem I needed to use getName() instead of getSimpleName().

Comment: @GennadiiIanchev thanks.. so rare to find perfect answers in comments.